# one variable in another variable in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, instantiation

i need to make something like this...

```
class Warrior{
   public String weapon;
   public String armor;
}

String[] SublimeArray = new String[5];
for(int x = 0; x <= SublimeArray.Length; x++){

         Warrior aquiles(x)  = new Warrior();
         SublimeArray[x]  = aquiles(x);

}

//It give me something like that....
//   Warrior aquiles1 = new Warrior();
//   SublimeArray[1] = aquiles1;
//   Warrior aquiles2 = new Warrior();
//   SublimeArray[2] = aquiles2;
//   Warrior aquiles3 = new Warrior();
//   SublimeArray[3] = aquiles1;
//            .
//            .
//            .
```

how can a I make this in c#...a variable into another declaration of another variable...
(this code example is a part of a hash funcion, an open hashing example, and I want to put a dinamic structure in an array... )

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: `var sublimeArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => new Warrior()).ToArray();` ?

Comment: Why isn't the array of type Warrior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up the naming of variables and giving an object a so-called "name".

When it comes to creating your `Warrior` objects, you don't need to store each object (`Warrior`) with a new variable name because you will be accessing them from the array. What I mean to say is, instead of trying to name each new `Warrior` like this: aquiles1, aquiles2, etc. you just create them directly in the array and access them from there.

So, in order to create an array of `Warrior`s, you could do this:

```
Warrior[] SublimeArray = new Warrior[5];
for(int x = 0; x <= SublimeArray.Length; x++){
     SublimeArray[x]  = new Warrior();
}
```

Notice that I changed the type of the array to `Warrior` instead of `String`. An array with type `String` cannot hold anything other than `String` variables.

Now, in order to access these new warriors you created, you would just index the array. So, to access the first `Warrior`, you would do this:

```
SublimeArray[0].Weapon = "Dragon Halberd";
```

Or, to access the last one:

```
SublimeArray[4].Armor = "Rune Plate Armor";
```

As you can see, you don't need to give each `Warrior` a new variable name, you just access them through the array.

*I should note that I capitalized the property names (Weapon and Armor) because the standard naming convention for public properties is PascalCase.*